# Java: Stuck inside if statement block

Tags: java, android, if-statement

i am starting with creating android apps, i already have some basic experience with C# and Java. Now i'm stuck at a strange problem, see below:

```
public void pictureSwitch (View view){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVCat);
    boolean switched = false;

    if (switched){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.catstart);
        Log.i("Status-Start", "Wert: " +  switched);
        switched = false;
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.catswitch);
        Log.i("Status-switched", "Wert: " +  switched);
       switched = true;
    }

    }

}
```

The Problem is, on the first click on the Button it changes to the catswitch drawable. But it never switches back and i dont know why.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Because every time you enter this method you set `switched` to false. It will never go into the `if` block.

Comment: `switched` is _always_ false when it hits your `if` statement, due to this statement: `boolean switched = false;`.

Comment: A variable local to a method cannot be used to maintain a state. Use a field of some class for that.

Comment: `switched` needs to be defined outside the method, it gets set to `false` everytime the method is invoked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets have a `boolean` as instance variable.

```
  private  boolean switched = false;
public void pictureSwitch() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVCat);
    if (switched) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.catstart);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.catswitch);
    }
    switched = !switched;
}
```

And you do not need a parameter `View view` if you are not using it .

Comment: Oh man.. thats a dumb mistake. Thanks to all for quick solution.